# Writing two commands into terminal using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

With an AppleScript I am trying to open a terminal window and set the terminal to cd into certain folders.  I want the terminal to cd into multiple folders. but it keeps opening up 2 windows and doing the 2 commands in 2 separate windows.

```
set desktop_folder to "$HOME/Desktop"
tell application "Terminal"
do script "cd desktop"
do script "cd myfolder"
end tell
```

how can i set it so that the terminal will execute these commands in the same window?

Comment: Is it really two `cd` commands? If so, what's wrong with `cd desktop/myfolder`?

Answer (score 1):

Every **do script** command of Terminal.app opens new window. So, to send multiple commands to the same window, you should use **only one do script** command. Like here:

```
set desktop_folder to "$HOME/Desktop"
set myfolder to quoted form of (POSIX path of (choose folder))

tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd " & desktop_folder & ";cd " & myfolder
```

**Note**: this approach has little advantage - it  successfully  creates window 1 when no windows exists already.

Comment: *Every do script command of Terminal.app opens new window*. This is true unless you  append `in window 1` to every line. Then all commends are executed in the frontmost window.

Comment: I wrote the note

Comment: In addition, there is no need to keep track of the indexing of windows. But in principle, your answer is already the correct solution and my answer gives a slight improvement. It all depends on the preferences of the end user.